# How to Make a turtle Move within Polygons?

Tags: gis, netlogo, shapefile

I am creating model in netlogo using GIS extension to read shapefiles. I have polygons representing a National Park and points representing lions. The points and park's polygon display without any problem. However, I want to create turtles from the points, that is where I get a problem. When I do that turtles change position. They are arranged in the same pattern but they spread and occupy the whole netlogo's world, as opposed to being a small cluster within the park.

```
extensions [gis]  
globals [lion-dataset  park-dataset] 

to setup
ca    
reset-ticks 

;; import national park shapefile  

set park-dataset gis:load-dataset "H:/college/reserve_lion.shp 
gis:set-drawing-color green gis:fill park-dataset 2.0  

;; read in turtle dataset and draw  
set lion-dataset gis:load-dataset "H:/college/lion.shp 
gis:set-drawing-color red gis:fill park-dataset 2.0  

breed [lions lion]   

;; creating the turtle from lion-dataset    
foreach gis:feature-list-of lion-dataset  
[   let location gis:location-of gis:centroid-of ?   
if not empty? location  
[ create-lions 1        
[ set shape "person"      
  set size 1      
  set color red      
  set xcor gis:property-value ? " x_park"      
  set xcor gis:property-value ? " y_park"                 
  show "world loaded"          

end        

to go            
ask lions            
[move]            
tick          
end        

to move            
fd 3      
rt 3          
end
```